# how to save the data using django channel to postgresql

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-channels

I'm trying to save the data that send using django channel and postgresql.

consumers.py

```
   async def connect(self):
        event = eventhubreader.EventReader()
        async def cb(partition, events):
            data = events[len(events)-1]
            await self.send(json.dumps({'value': data.body_as_json()}))
            now = datetime.now()
            dataFormat = {"IotData": {"temperature": data.body_as_json()["temperature"], "humidity": data.body_as_json()["humidity"]}, "MessageDate": now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S"), "DeviceId": data.body_as_json()['deviceId']}
            saverecord = Rawdata()
            saverecord.ref_waterplant = random.randint(20, 25)
            saverecord.created_at = dataFormat['MessageDate']
            saverecord.is_live = True
            saverecord.save()
            print(dataFormat)
        await self.accept()
```

models.py

```
class Rawdata(models.Model):
    ref_waterplant = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    created_at = models.DateField()
    is_live = True
    
    class Meta:
        db_table = "rawdata"
```

error

```
An error occurred while receiving. The exception is SynchronousOnlyOperation('You cannot call this from an async context - use a thread or sync_to_async.').
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make seperate function for saving entry in database and call and you can return also if you want

```
from channels.db import database_sync_to_async

async def connect(self):
    await self.save_entry()
    #more code----

@database_sync_to_async
def save_entry(self):
    saverecord = Rawdata()
    saverecord.ref_waterplant = random.randint(20, 25)
    saverecord.created_at = dataFormat['MessageDate']
    saverecord.is_live = True
    saverecord.save()
    return
```

Comment: it's running but not saving to postgres

Comment: any error in console ?